# Entity Framework 7 - Migrations : how to specify database provider and connection string just for migrations

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way how to specify which DataProvider(SQL Server) and ConnectionString to use just for generating a migrations(Add-Migration) and updating a database(Update-Database)? I do not want to hardcode the data provider selection and connection string loading into DbContext (.UseSqlServer()).

I think EF6 can pick a connection string directly from web.config, is there something similar in EF7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you have to use optionsBuilder:

example:

```
string oldConnectionString =@"Server = .\;Initial Catalog=EFTutorial; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\EFTutorial.mdf; Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true";

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(oldConnectionString );
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

you can also load as json and load it directly from app.config or web.config.

If you are using .Net Core:

you can define in your appsettings.json the conenction string as following:

```
{
  {
     ....

  },
  "Data": {
           "ConnectionString": "..."   
  }
}
```

on App starting you have to load it:

```
// Set up configuration sources.
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
Configuration = builder.Build().ReloadOnChanged("appsettings.json");
```

After that you also have to configure Entity Framework in Startup.cs.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<AppContext>(options =>
 { 
                     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration "Data:ConnectionString"]); });
        services.AddScoped<AppContext, AppContext>();

        ...
  }
}
```

The improtant thing here:

```
services.AddScoped((_) => new AppContext(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html

Examples to conenction string in Entity Framework Core 1.0 / 7:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

The old way(You can do that also with EF Core) we have load the conenctionString from App.config or web.config
and by the Migration process Add-Migration/Update-Database, EF will automatically found the Connection string.
But you can also provide the conenction string to Add-Migration in the NuGet  comamnd line as parameter.

I hope this will solve your Problem!

Comment: Well this is not very good approach, or am I missing something? Imagine you have a Class Library for you Entities and DbContext. You want to enable migrations for this class library project. Hardcoding databsae provider selection and connection string is not good as for example you want to us InMemory or different database provider/connection string later, in the production code.

Comment: no this is just an example to show you that is work, do not have to hardcode your conenction string this is not a good idea. I will update my answer and I will add the normal apporach.

Comment: I did not know I can provide a connection string to " Add-Migration". Anyway, thank you. Problem solved.